# Changing rates and Pythagorean Theorem. Calculus

Tags: calculus

[image]

I'm taking a course through Berkeley and I saw this video. Shouldn't the number not be 99.5? Why is `d(t)` == 99.5? Why are we subtracting $100^2 - 10^2$ and not adding by the pythagorean theorum?

Comment: It seems there is a typo!

Comment: @Jwan622 : Well spotted. Clearly $d(4) = \sqrt{10^2+100^2} \approx 100.5$.